# Allauth form is not displayed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-allauth

Using Django 1.4 and latest allauth I have strange issue with forms not being displayed:

This is the settings.py:

```
     MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
     # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 )


INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# 'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'bootstrap_toolkit',
'demo_app',
'south',
```

)

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"allauth.account.context_processors.account",
"allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
"django.core.context_processors.csrf",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
```

)

This is the template which is causing me problems:
password_reset.html

```
    {% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Password Reset" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{% trans "Password Reset" %}</h1>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% include "account/snippets/already_logged_in.html" %}
    {% endif %}

    <p>{% trans "Forgotten your password? Enter your e-mail address below, and we'll send you an e-mail allowing you to reset it." %}</p>

    <form method="POST" action="" class="password_reset">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ password_reset_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Reset My Password" %}" />
    </form>

    <p>{% blocktrans %}Please contact us if you have any trouble resetting your password.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_body %}
    <script>
        $("#id_email").focus();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the part which is not handled:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="password_reset">{% csrf_token %}
{{ password_reset_form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Reset My Password" %}" />
</form>""
```

I also tried to take of the csrf_token , the result html I am getting is following:

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
 <legend>Password reset</legend>
 <p>Forgotten your password? Enter your email address below, and we'll send you an email allowing you to reset it.</p>
 <fieldset>
 <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='XaG5EyB6JY70kkQrsqTFnQ6wzPXujMpg' /></div>        
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset my password</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<p>If you have any trouble resetting your password, contact us at <a href="mailto:"></a>.      </p>
```

Comment: When I debug in eclipse the password_reset_form is correctly filled in:

ResetPasswordForm: <tr><th><label for="id_email">E-mail:</label></th></td><input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" size="30" /></td></tr>

Comment: my fault, had the duplicated templates from django-pinax project which are named the same way :(